# Convert PostgreSQL Serial Primary Key to Oracle Statement

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, netbeans, oracle11g

I have a java file that connects to a database and this is the code:

```
package movies;

import java.sql.*;

public class CreateTable {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String sql;
try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");//driver
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE", "username", "password");//PUT DATABASE CONNECTION INFO  
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully from within CreateTable.java");
        stmt = c.createStatement();

        sql = "CREATE TABLE MOVIES "
                //+ "(ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"//can't figure out this statement and it works if I comment it out.
                + " (NAME         NVARCHAR2(255) PRIMARY KEY,"//I don't want this to be the primary key.
                + " YEAR          NVARCHAR2(255),"
                + " RATING        NVARCHAR2(16),"
                + " ACTORS        NVARCHAR2(1024))";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Table created successfully");
    }
}
```

The commented part is where I'm running into problems.  I'm trying to convert a PostgreSQL statement to an Oracle 11g XE statement.  I would like to have an ID with a sequential number to identify it.  (ie. 0001, 0002, 0003, etc.)  How can I do this?  Could you provide an example?  I'm at a loss right now.  I'm using Netbeans 8.02, Oracle 11g XE, and Apache Tomcat 8.0.15.0.

*edit* I'm trying to have the ID column as the only primary key.  I would eliminate the NAME column as a primary key and make the ID column the new primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have two separate columns with primary key like that, if you want a primary key on two columns use,

```
edit :


 sql = "CREATE TABLE MOVIES "
                + "(ID  INT PRIMARY KEY,"  -- CHANGES
                + " NAME         NVARCHAR2(255),"
                + " YEAR          NVARCHAR2(255),"
                + " RATING        NVARCHAR2(16),"
                + " ACTORS        NVARCHAR2(1024))";
```

i have created the table to show the syntax works in oracle now..

```
SQL>   create table movies
  2                               (id int primary key,
  3                               name NVARCHAR2(255),
  4                               year NVARCHAR2(255),
  5                               rating NVARCHAR2(255),
  6                               actors NVARCHAR2(1024));

Table created.
```

Comment: `+ "(ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"`
does not work, nor does `+ "(ID  SERIAL,"`  I'm only trying to have the `ID` column as the primary key.  Not two primary keys.  Sorry about that.

Comment: it will not work if you have,   + "(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"  and " (NAME         NVARCHAR2(255) PRIMARY KEY,"  both together in your  create statement

Comment: My problem is that the ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY is a PostgreSQL statement.  I'm trying to convert it to an Oracle 11g XE statement.

Comment: Please see the changes now

Comment: It should be fixed now, there was an extra "(" also before the NAME, loose that. see the changes above

Answer (score 0):

This code worked.  See the comments below to view the changes:

```
        try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");//driver
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE", "username", "password");//PUT DATABASE CONNECTION INFO  
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully from within CreateTable.java");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        sql = "CREATE TABLE MOVIES "
                //THE FOLLOWING LINE WAS CHANGED:
                + "(\"ID\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, \"TYPE\" VARCHAR2(32),"
                + " NAME         NVARCHAR2(255),"
                + " YEAR          NVARCHAR2(255),"
                + " RATING        NVARCHAR2(16),"
                + " ACTORS        NVARCHAR2(1024))";

        //THE FOLLOW TWO STATEMENTS WERE ADDED:
        String sql1 = "CREATE SEQUENCE MOVIES_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE";
        String sql2 = "CREATE TRIGGER MOVIES_TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON MOVIES FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT MOVIES_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL; END;";

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        //THESE TWO WERE ALSO ADDED:
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```